# How to make a file in a specific directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I would like to make a file in a specific "accounts" directory but I keep getting the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/accounts/Jason Silla.txt'
```

This is my code, so if anyone can explain what is happening. I am on the latest version of python on a Mac.

```
filePath = join("/accounts", username + ".txt")
newuser = open(filePath, "w")
newuser.write(username + "\n" + password)
```

Also I have seen the other posts about this but as you can see it is not working for me. I did import join from os.path so that is not the issue.

Comment: I don't think such a (relative?) path is valid. The path you open should be of the format `<drive>:\...\accounts\<username>.txt`. The part `<drive>:\...` is missing.

Comment: Does the folder "accounts" exist already? You cannot write a file in a folder that doesn't exist. Create it manually or with os.mkdir() (you probably want to check if it exists before)

Comment: If your accounts directory is in the current directory you don't need the first /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to refer to your directory as `"/accounts"` but instead refer to it as `"accounts"`.  When you use a leading slash `/` at the beginning of a file name, then you are referring to a directory relative to the root of your entire file storage tree.  If there is not leading slash, then you are referring to a directory relative to the current local directory where your script is being run.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your *accounts* directory exists, if not, create it.

```
try:
    # remove leading '/' if you want to work in the current directory
    os.makedirs("accounts")  
except FileExistsError:
    # directory already exists
    newuser = open(filePath, "w") 
    # etc etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that there is an 'accounts' directory in the same directory where this python file you are running is located, if not just create i